# Potentially dangerous Form value (Asp.net attack using fault page)

Tags: asp.net, security

I have health monitor running over my ASP.NET site, I have seen a multiple attacks on my site using

```
http://SiteName/Page.aspx/Comment.asp?Id=76 (each request the ID is changing)
```

Comment.asp page is not a part of my site, it is been used by attacker not sure what it does. If I open my site appending comment.asp`(http://sitename/page.aspx/comment.asp?id=1)` the result is my aspx page which is strange to me. on my page.aspx pageload event I am trying to catch the request.URL where comment.asp doesn't appearing in this case.

Request exception details:

Do I have to worry for such attacks,how can I prevent them. I have given already IP restrictions but each time the request is coming from different IPs. However I haven't seen any implications of this attack over my site. as per the IP all the bad requests are coming from China(as per IP finder).

```
at ASP.xxxxxxxx_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

what is the above line in the stack trace? thats my aspx page, asp.net engine process like that? haven't seen that.still everyday I get this attack with dangerous form value detected notification through healthmonitor.

Comment: I rid of this issue by replacing query string with crosspageposting and also added a check if URL contains non expected chars display 404 page.Where ever possible use alternate to querystring. blackhats is a bot and it is not harming my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, does Page.aspx/Comment.asp?Id=76 make sense for your application? If not, it might be that the requests you see are coming from a botnet that tries to find an explicit exploit or unprotected content in the wild. Now and then it comes along your url and you will find the entry in your log as shown. I had such things on my website daily

Comment: It doesn't do anything with mysite.Not exploiting any info in the case of exception redirects to an other default page. Logs info is 404 error since that page is not exist.

Comment: strange behaviour, forgot to mention it. If the request is going to Page.aspx/comment.asp, the page.aspx is being displayed in the browser.Why is that behaviour actually there is not comment.asp exists in my site.

Comment: It is not strange behaviour it should handle the slash that way. (It could for example be used to address an endpoint) You do not have to worry about it.

Comment: When Comment.asp page is not exists in the directory and processing the given url for previous page (page.aspx) is not correct and it is not common.Something wrong !!

Comment: Could you explain in facts why you think there is something wrong?

Comment: This user(from china) is not expected in our site, getting hits in the odd time everyday,last week 40 hits using the same page and I have been notified about potentially dangerous request.Which obviously sure that attacker.When there is not page in my directory nor IIS, IIS is processing the page.

Comment: The potentially dangerous request exceptions come from asp.net request validation. Apparently the http request contains some injection or xss statements that request validation does not like. My answer still stands. I think it is just a bot that searches in the wild for vulnerabilities where it comes along your website so now and then.

Comment: I understand asp.net engine first validates the request and throwing the exception which is falling under the application error class and health monitor is triggering the email notification.I was actually thinking that health monitor sends the email if there is any issue in the written code behind page, but this is not, with this concludes that can even occurs beyond our code and before actual code starts IIS--Asp.net -- before pageinit.

Comment: Request validation throws exceptions that you will need to handle on application level: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately our site is running in framework 3.5, Request validation is available from .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: That is not true. Request validation is also available in framework 3.5. Check this out: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation

Comment: Thanks for correcting, this is something that I had never looked since its default feature, however cause for my confusion is this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx, frame work version selection doesn't showing for 2.0 3.0 3.5